# Problem when integrating $z^n$ around unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Sorry for the vague title but saw no other way of describing it without being annoyingly specific.

The problem is to do contour integration of $\int_\gamma f(z)$ where $f(z) = z^n, n\geqslant0$ and $\gamma$ is the circle centered at 0 with a radius of R.

According to one of the theorems from my course, if $f$ is integrable over $[0,2\pi]$, then I can simply compute this problem by doing $F(2\pi) - F(0)$. However, this is not giving me the answer I $\it{know}$ to be true, which is $0$.

I know the answer is $0$ because the theorem implies that the contour integrals of integrable functions over closed contours are always $0$. However, when I do the calculation here, I get $\frac{2\pi^{n+1}}{n+1}$. I don't understand why the theorem is not yielding the expected result.

I even calculated the answer using the classical definition and got the right answer. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Also, I have yet to go over the Residual Theorem at this time.

Comment: You need to parameterise the circle in order to change this into a real integral, i.e., you need to express $f(z)$ in terms of $R\cos\theta$ and $R\sin\theta$, and then you integrate over $[0,2\pi]$ $d\theta$. What you did there is like ignoring a change of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just change the limits, what you're doing here is the complex equivalent to "change of variable", you need to make sure everything matches up. The idea is to express the curve as a function of $t$, so that as $t$ changes, we "travel along" the curve (this is called *parameterisation* of the curve). Usually $t$ ranges over an interval $[t_1, t_2]$.

For simplicity, take the unit circle $\gamma$. You should know that we can parameterise this curve as a function of $t$, writing [$\gamma(t) = \cos t + i \sin t$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eyj9ovbi9e) for [$t\in[0,2\pi]$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eyj9ovbi9e). Then to change everything in terms of $t$, we do

\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}(f\circ\gamma)(t)\,\gamma'(t)\,dt\\[3pt]
&= \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos t+i \sin t)^n\,(\sin t-i\cos t)\,dt\\[3pt]
&= \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos nt+i \sin nt)\,(\sin t-i\cos t)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}(\cos((n+1)t) + i\sin((n+1)t))\,dt=0,
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. That should have been obvious to me. However, isn't what you wrote more akin to  using the formal definition? If I wanted to use the theorem I stated in my question - this time by expressing $f(z)$ in terms of $cos$ and $sin$ - that would be valid? And in the case that the function is not integrable, I should use the method you have? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is exactly substitution in the formal definition. For your second question, yes, that's what I did, I wrote $f(z) = (\cos t + i \sin t)^n$ since we substituted that for $z$. If the function is not integrable, then you can't integrate it!

Comment: It's good to compare the formal definition with how change of variables works:
$$\int_a^b f(u)\, du = \int_{u^{-1}(a)}^{u^{-1}(b)} f(u(x))\, u'(x)\, dx.$$

Comment: I think I see where I'm a little confused (apart from the huge conceptual problem you've just clarified for me). My class notes seem to make a distinction between doing $\int_\gamma f(z) = \int_a^b f(\gamma (t))\gamma'(t)dt$ and $\int_\gamma f(z) = F(b) - F(a)$, but they're in the exact thing conceptualized differently. Is that right? Because I was viewing the latter as some method that makes it easier when certain conditions apply - which I'm now seeing doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If we're being precise, I'm assuming $[a,b]$ is the interval over which $\gamma$ is parameterised? In that case, the fundamental theorem of calculus (adapted for complex analysis) asserts that $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a)),$$ i.e., you evaluate the function $F$ at the end points of the curve itself (not at $a$ and $b$!). Since the curve is closed in our case (the same starting point and end point, $1 + 0i$) then it's $$F(\gamma(2\pi)) - F(\gamma(0))=\frac{(1+0i)^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{(1+0i)^{n+1}}{n+1} = 0.$$

Comment: Notice that this should makes sense because in general, we could parameterise curves in various different ways, e.g. in our case, we can change the interval to $[a, a+2\pi]$ for some $a\neq 0$. The value of our integral should not depend on these values! ($F(b) - F(a)$ could be different if we parameterise differently, but $F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))$ depends solely on the curve).

Answer (score 2):

The interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is a parametrization of $\gamma$, not the start and endpoints of the contour. A standard parametrization: $$\gamma = \{\phi(t) = Re^{it} : t \in [0, 2\pi] \}$$ 
With this, you see that $\phi(0) = \phi(2\pi) = R$, thus 
$$F(\phi(2\pi)) - F(\phi(0)) = F(R) - F(R) = 0$$